# Вывести повторяющие данные один раз

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с данными:

```
Dialog id: 12345
Dialog id: 12345
Dialog id: 12346
```

Нужно вывести:

```
Dialog id: 12345
Dialog id: 12346
```

Вот код вывода:

```
$dialogs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konsultant");
while ($dia = mysql_fetch_array($dialogs)) 
{
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:0px;">'.$dia['dialog_id'].'</td>
        <td style="border-bottom:0px;">'.$dia['client_ip'].'</td>
        <td style="border-bottom:0px;">'.$dia['client_msg'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не сильно уверен, что запрос вида

```
SELECT `id`, `dialog_id`, `client_ip`, `client_msg`  
FROM konsultant
GROUP BY dialog_id
```

даст желаемый результат.
Поэтому если чуть усложнить и сделать так:

```
SELECT k.`id`, k.`dialog_id`, k.`client_ip`, k.`client_msg`
FROM konsultant k, (SELECT id
        FROM konsultant 
        GROUP BY dialog_id
) AS temp
WHERE k.`id` = temp.`id`
```

Должно помочь и изначально выбрать одиночные записи. Ибо в подзапросе мы выберем так, чтоб получить индивидуальные записи, а в основном уже это учтем.

И тогда в цикле просто пробегаемся по всем выбранным записям и делаем, что хотим

Comment: Вроде работает  GROUP BY dialog_id.Спасибо

Comment: @Sauron я просто боюсь, что банальный `GROUP BY dialog_id` сгруппирует как-то не так данные из столбцов

Comment: Я попоробовал вроде одно и тоже.Но я хотел получить с dialog_id самую последную запись интересно как это сделать...

Comment: `GROUP BY` берет произвольную строку группы. А еще нет сортировки. А вот то, что надо было брать из всех именно последнюю - надо было уточнить в вопросе с самого начала. Это ж важный момент)

Comment: Проста потому решил сделать `Последнее сообщение от клиента:`

Comment: Всё решил проблему вывод последнего сообщения: `SELECT k.'id', k.'dialog_id', k.'client_ip', k.'client_msg'
FROM konsultant k, (SELECT id
        FROM konsultant 
        ORDER BY id DESC
) AS temp
WHERE k.'id' = temp.'id' GROUP BY dialog_id`

Comment: @Sauron попробуйте в подзапрос вместо `SELECT id` написать `SELECT MAX(`id`) AS id`  должно помочь..... ну это во втором случае.... хотя и в первом должно помочь

Answer (score 0):

```
  $already_in = array(); // сюда будем добавлять полученные dialog_id 

  $dialogs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konsultant");

  while ($dia = mysql_fetch_array($dialogs)) {
    if(!in_array($dia['dialog_id'], $already_in)) { // если ещё не встречалось таких dialog_id
      $already_in[] = $dia['dialog_id'];

      echo '
      <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:0px;">'.$dia['dialog_id'].'</td>
          <td style="border-bottom:0px;">'.$dia['client_ip'].'</td>
          <td style="border-bottom:0px;">'.$dia['client_msg'].'</td>
      </tr>';
    }
  }
```